# How to write a query so that it only returns results where two columns are zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a single table that I need to join to itself, using a similar style to what I have below, even if there are other ways to solve.

I'm trying to **exclude** only rows that have **both** `Leftover` and `Remainder` equal to 0.

My problem is rows `C` and `F` keep getting excluded.

**All rows:**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Letter | Leftover | Remainder |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| A      |        1 |         2 |
| B      |        2 |         3 |
| C      |        3 |         0 |
| D      |        0 |         0 |
| E      |        0 |         0 |
| F      |        0 |         4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Letter | Leftover | Remainder |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| A      |        1 |         2 |
| B      |        2 |         3 |
| C      |        3 |         0 |
| F      |        0 |         4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

**Actual output:**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Letter | Leftover | Remainder |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| A      |        1 |         2 |
| B      |        2 |         3 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Here's my sample code:

```
create table #Temp
(
    Letter char,
    Leftover int,
    Remainder int
)


insert into #Temp values ('A', 1, 2 )
insert into #Temp values ('B', 2, 3 )
insert into #Temp values ('C', 3, 0 )
insert into #Temp values ('D', 0, 0)
insert into #Temp values ('E', 0, 0)
insert into #Temp values ('F', 0, 4)

select * from #Temp

select a.* from #Temp a
    join #Temp b on a.Letter = b.Letter
    where (b.Remainder != 0 AND b.Leftover != 0)



If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp
End
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Based on your description, you want D and E, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, I phrased it wrong. I just edited. I'm trying to exclude only the rows where both columns are zero, but if only one/none columns are zero, they should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `or`, not `and`:

```
where b.Remainder <> 0 or b.Leftover <> 0
```

Or, you can phrase this as:

```
where not (b.Remainder = 0 and b.Leftover = 0)
```

These are logically equivalent.

Comment: Bingo, I should have probably figured this out on my own, but it's apart of a larger query and I must have gotten tunnel vision

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the join. Try

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Temp AS T
WHERE
    T.Leftover = 0 AND T.Remainder = 0
```

This will give you rows D and E.

Alternatively `NOT (T.Leftover = 0 AND T.Remainder = 0)` will give you rows A, B, C and F.

What the join is saying is exclude rows where are least one of the items is zero.

For completeness:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    #Temp AS a
    JOIN 
    #Temp b on a.Letter = b.Letter
WHERE
    NOT (b.Leftover = 0 AND b.Remainder = 0)
```

Comment: I accidentally said include when I meant exclude. I edited the main post. I need to do the join because I'm working with a special software application where any filters on the main table are displayed to the user and can be modified. The application allows me to join another table to it, so I'm limited to that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select * from #temp
where leftover+remainder>0
```